# AngularJS - Close current window tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been trying to get this work in my angular project, searching over the internet and it seems none of the possibles answers are helping me.

My console says:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Because I'm trying to close my current window with a button.

```
<button onclick="window.close();">Close window</button>
```

and of course the reasons is described at the console message. I can not close this window because this was not opened by javascript. At the first time my close window button was inside a `ng-view` and didn't work, after that I've moved my button to my index page outside the `ng-view` getting the same result :(

After those changes and other more that I've been found on internet, I've created a project from scratch, simple app, basically working just with the `ng-app` on `index.html` and a couple of controller that do nothing. AND this button works.

**This works:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">    
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    <button onclick="window.close();">Close window</button>
</body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="MyControllers.js"></script>
</html>
```

**This is not working:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>my web</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <my-nav-bar></my-nav-bar>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <button onclick="window.close();">Close window</button>

    <script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/myapp/myapp.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/myapp/mycontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/myapp/mydirectives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It says `scripts may close only the windows that were opened by javascript` but can anyone makes me notice if there any diference between this two html? if it's not, **How the first html is following this rule and the second one doesn't'?**

Comment: Both work when opened as local files and both DO NOT work when hosted by webserver

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: @KirillSlatin you are absolutely right man. I've just figure it out. I'm gonna check the link in your other comment.

Comment: found few links why you can't do it. A security violation. [link1][1] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome           [2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314729/close-windows-that-were-not-opened-by-script-using-javascript